# Excel VBA - Setting one-row worksheet range of formula to blank multi-row range, relative references skipping rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference, range

Excel VBA - Setting one-row worksheet range of relative formula to blank multi-row range, relative references skipping rows

I'm trying to create a macro for users of an Excel workbook template to:

1) add rows inside a named range,

2) move the last record in this named range to the top row in this range of new rows (to maintain the bounds of the named range and preserve the order of any user-input records), and

3) fill these new rows with formula from a master row.

Where I'm stuck is when the master row formula are set to this range of multiple blank rows, the relative references (after the first row) skip a row.  For example, if the first row in this range is, say, Row 16, then:

Row 16 has a formula reference to A16,

Row 17 has that reference set to A18,

Row 18 has that reference set to A20,
etc.

Below is the sub meant to perform this task:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddRows( _
    ByRef rrngInputFields As Range, _
    ByRef rrngMasterRow As Range, _
    ByVal intRowsToAdd As Long)
    'Add rows to worksheet
        'rrngInputFields is the named range that defines user input fields
        'rrngMasterRow is the row that contains template formula
        'intRowsToAdd is the number of rows to add, determined by the user

    Dim rngRefRow                       As Range

    Dim rngLastRecordOldRow             As Range
    Dim intLastRecordNewNo              As Integer

    Dim rngNewRows                      As Range
    Dim rngLastRecordNewRow             As Range
    Dim intCountCol                     As Integer

    'Set the last user record in the user input range
        'New rows will be added above this to preserve the range
    Set rngRefRow _
        = rrngInputFields.Cells(rrngInputFields.Rows.Count, 1).EntireRow

    'Set the last user record to later be moved to the top of the added rows
        'This will maintain the order the user input their data
    Set rngLastRecordOldRow = rngRefRow
    intLastRecordNewNo = rngRefRow.Row

    'Add the new rows
    rngRefRow.Resize(intRowsToAdd).Insert

    intCountCol = rrngMasterRow.Columns.Count

    'Set the range of new rows that will receive the template formula and formatting
    Set rngNewRows _
        = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(intLastRecordNewNo + 1, 1), _
        Cells(intLastRecordNewNo + intRowsToAdd, intCountCol))

    'Set the row to move the last user input record
    Set rngLastRecordNewRow = ActiveSheet.Rows(intLastRecordNewNo)

    'Move the last user record to the bottom of the existing records
    rngLastRecordNewRow.FormulaR1C1 = rngLastRecordOldRow.FormulaR1C1

    'Copy the master row, including all formulas and formatting, to the added rows
    rngNewRows.FormulaR1C1 = rrngMasterRow.FormulaR1C1

End Sub
```

The last line is where the issue presents itself.

What would cause this skip in the relative reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the range.range effect described [in remarks here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.range). A solution is to use the [range.copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy) method like this

```
'rngNewRows.FormulaR1C1 = rrngMasterRow.FormulaR1C1
rrngMasterRow.Copy rngNewRows
```

Comment: In the end, I did end up using range.copy after exploring alternatives.  So if I understand it right, because it's a range within a range, it's treated like a relative reference?  Would using `ActiveSheet.Cells` be treated as an absolute reference?

Comment: @SquirrelBait  I think it depends on the context, I would just test it and see.